# Error when trying to move Photos Library

Tags: macos, hard-drive, photos, library

Can't find a likely looking existing question so here goes:
I just updated to Yosemite and successfully (??  well -- it seems to work ) migrated my iPhoto library to Photos.  Now however, I would like to move the iPhoto library to another external drive.
It is already on an external but I got a new one that I want **dedicated** to photos only).

So I thought I should quit Photos and copy the library to the brand new pristine drive.  It looks like it's doing a major copy with a progress bar and all, and clanks and grinds for a long time then about halfway through it keels on an error,

> The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in “Photos
>   Library” can't be read or written (Error code -36)

and I wind up with nothing on the new disk.

So my question really what is wrong with the Photos library to begin with and how do I fix it?

Comment: Applications like iPhoto, Photo, and Lightroom are essentially databases for image files. With databases, you always want to move files within the application and not through the Finder, so that they can rewrite the links to where the data lies on the disk or volume. LR allows you to find broken links, but I haven't seen that functionality in Photos. You may just want to mover everything back to the original folder and see if you get access back. If it was the old iPhotos library you moved and not the new Photos library, then I am not sure why Photos is giving you problems.

Comment: Yes I am aware that inband file movement is preferable, but all the googles said go out of band and just move the WHOLE shebang and then make the Photos app point to it.  The original folder is intact and still works.  It was an IPhoto library that had recently been migrated to Photos and seemed to work OK.  In fact I still have a file called iPhoto library as well.  How do I diagnose what is wrong with it.

Comment: So I read your question incorrectly. There is likely nothing "Wrong" with the photos library. See this, http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/21/fix-error-code-36-finder-mac-os-x/ but try with caution... I would do a Time Machine backup first incase the Photos library gets corrupted.

Comment: More importantly, the way I found that was Google **error code 36 finder** and that was the first page.

Comment: Thanks.  I googled that same and found do the copy through terminal because the cp -R will spit a warning about a bad file and continue where as Finder will give up.   (That solution is even more out of band).   More importantly I don't know where the inband DB management menu items are.  I am new to Photos,  I was looking for some advanced menu or something,  but couldn't find any.

Comment: did dot_clean.  It ran in terminal without hiccup. (took a little whie)  STILL getting error 36.  Now I will try the cp -R from terminal.

Comment: Is the drive that you are copying to formatted in journaled HFS+ or EXFat? I have had a problem with Yosemite and trying to transfer between file systems on USB drives. It doesn't seem to be an issue for network files. Likely a different transfer protocol used fro USB than TCP/IP.

Comment: The new drive is journaled HFS+  and it is USB,  so is the old one.

Comment: I used cp -R in terminal and now I have a whole bunch of folders and whatnot on the new drive ... stuff I guess was hidden under Photos Library before.   Got a few warnings during the cp, but it soldiered on like the googles said it would. But what I don't have is a Photos Library file I can point the app at.

Comment: I pointed Photos at the outer folder that was intended to be a container.  It works.  I can retire this other drive now.  Let's hear it for primitive command line tools.  Yay!